# Backwards compatible contains()

Tags: matlab, backwards-compatibility

I'm writing a set of functions that will be used by colleagues who use older versions of MATLAB (2015a/2015b). In one of my functions I use `contains()` which was only introduced in 2016b and is thus not backward compatible. I'd like to provide a workaround but I'm not quite sure how to go about this. The particular issue that I'm dealing with is as follows:

```
files = {'/some/path/sub001file','/some/path/sub002file','/some/path/sub003file'};
subjects = {'sub001','sub003'};
files = files(contains(files,subjects))
```

I'm looking for a way to replace the third line with one that will run on MATLAB2015a and later, and provides identical output. As an aside, since this is a rather small operation the readability of the code is more important than computational efficiency.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bit convoluted, but the following will work,

```
idx = cellfun(@(c)~all(cellfun(@(d)isempty(strfind(c,d)),subjects)),files);
files = files(idx);
```

Comment: ...Holy mother of code. Well it works. I'll spend the next few minutes figuring out how though ;). Thanks!

Comment: It's basically just a nested loop.  The outer loop goes over all elements of `files`, and the inner loop goes over all elements of `subjects`.  If any of the elements of `subjects` is contained within an element of `files` then the corresponding element of `idx` is set to `true`.